# TypeScript 1.8 definition file Enum for 'magic string' properties

Tags: javascript, enums, typescript

I have a js lib I need to use in a tsc 1.8 project. One of its option properties is a magic string which states it only supports a few values, ie 'default', 'option 1', 'option 2'. In my .d.ts I would like to use an Enum for this value but cant work out how to do it. for example...

*loggerjs.js (external lib example)*

```
var loggerjs = (function(){
    function log(severity) {
        var message;

        if (severity === "High") {
            message = "OMG!";
        }
        else if (severity === "Low") {
            message = "meh";
        }

        console.log(message)
    }
});
```

*loggerjs.d.ts*

```
declare module "loggerjs" {
    export enum Severity {
        "Low",
        "High"
    }

    export function log(severity: Severity);
}
```

*require config*

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '',
    paths: {
        app: ''
    },
    shim:{
        'loggerjs':{
            exports:'loggerjs'
        }
    }
});

requirejs(['app']);
```

*app.ts*

```
import * as loggerjs from "loggerjs";
loggerjs.log(loggerjs.Severity.Low);
```

*app.js (compiled js)*

```
define(["require", "exports", "loggerjs"], function (require, exports, loggerjs) {
    "use strict";
    loggerjs.log(loggerjs.Severity.Low);
});
```

The above results in

> app.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Low' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enum isn't what you're after because that js uses strings.
You're getting that error because the actual implementation does not have that enum, you only declared that it does.

What you are looking for is called [String Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) and it would look like this:

```
declare module "loggerjs" {
    export type Severity = "Low" | "High";

    export function log(severity: Severity);
}
```

Comment: Thats great thanks, once i can mark as answer i will. I am now however getting "Uncaught TypeError: loggerjs.log is not a function(…)". any ideas? (editing to include require config)

Comment: I'll need to see the modified code which produces that error

Comment: This is a runtime error, are you sure that there's such a thing as `loggerjs.log`? What happens when you do `console.log(loggerjs.log)`?

Comment: that log returns undefined, typeing 'loggerjs' in console returns "function (){
    function log(severity) {
        var message;

        if (severity === "High") {
            message = "OMG!";
        }
        else if (severity === "Low") {
            me…"

Comment: So there's a problem with the js file, or you misunderstood how to use it..  Based on your comment you should do: `loggerjs('Low')`

Comment: i tried that but it just returns undefined. Just put the code on github, if you able to take a look. https://github.com/tgriley/TypeScriptDefinitionExample. Shall i put this in another question?

Comment: yeah, it's another question, and i'm not a requirejs expert so you'd be better off with someone else